# Нет подключения к redis

Tags: c#, windows, консоль, redis

Пытаюсь установить подключение с Redis на localhost.

```cs
string connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("RedisConnection");

_redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(connectionString); //Исключение

_database = _redis.GetDatabase();
```

Сама строка подключения из user-secrets:

```
"ConnectionStrings:RedisConnection": "redis://localhost:6379/",
```

Сама строка точно не null

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в C# получаю такое исключение :

> StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException
> HResult=0x80131500
> Message=It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s). Error connecting right now. To allow this multiplexer to continue retrying until it's able to connect, use abortConnect=false in your connection string or AbortOnConnectFail=false; in your code.
> Source=StackExchange.Redis
> StackTrace:
> at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ConnectImpl(ConfigurationOptions configuration, TextWriter log, Nullable`1 serverType, EndPointCollection endpoints) at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(ConfigurationOptions configuration, TextWriter log) at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(String configuration, TextWriter log) at FileCryptWeb.DataBase.Redis.RedisDbContext..ctor() in C:\Users\Stewi\Source\Repos\air2921\FileCryptWeb\FileCryptWeb\DataBase\Redis\RedisDbContext.cs:line 19 at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor) at System.Reflection.ConstructorInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr) at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()

Попытка запуска сервера

```
C:\Users\Stewi>cd C:\Program Files\Redis

C:\Program Files\Redis>redis-server.exe "C:\Program Files\Redis\redis.windows.conf"
[11340] 12 Sep 01:14:15.298 # Creating Server TCP listening socket *:6379: bind: No error
```

Но в netstat этот порт не прослушивается :

```
C:\Users\Stewi>netstat

Active Connections

Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State

TCP    192.168.0.2:52525      162.159.133.234:https  ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:52791      stackoverflow:https    ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:52917      20.54.37.64:https      ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53017      ve1190:9251            ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53102      ve1190:9251            ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53132      ve1190:9251            ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53336      ve1190:9251            ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53352      ve1190:9251            ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53353      lb-140-82-112-25-iad:https  ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53433      ve1190:9251            ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53434      ve1190:9251            ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53437      ve1190:9251            ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53439      ve1190:9251            ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53443      ve1190:9251            ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53445      ve1190:9251            ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53446      ve1190:9251            ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53447      ve1190:9251            TIME_WAIT
TCP    192.168.0.2:53449      132.245.231.0:https    TIME_WAIT
TCP    192.168.0.2:53452      ve1190:9251            ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53453      ve1190:9251            ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53457      ve1190:9251            ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53458      ve1190:9251            ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53459      ve1190:9251            ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53461      ve1190:9251            ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53462      47:https               TIME_WAIT
TCP    192.168.0.2:53463      20.189.173.7:https     TIME_WAIT
TCP    192.168.0.2:53466      62.115.252.59:https    ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53467      132.245.231.0:https    ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53469      13.107.246.73:https    ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53470      52.108.8.254:https     ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53471      152.199.21.118:https   ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53472      204.79.197.222:https   ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53473      20.54.232.160:https    ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53474      47:https               TIME_WAIT
TCP    192.168.0.2:53475      ve1190:9251            ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53476      152.199.19.161:https   ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53477      a23-53-53-206:https    ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53478      20.42.128.98:https     ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53479      152.199.19.161:https   ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53480      a23-53-53-206:https    ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53481      20.42.128.98:https     ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53482      13.107.246.73:https    ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53483      13.69.109.131:https    ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53484      152.199.19.161:https   ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53485      13.107.5.88:https      ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53487      a23-35-104-91:https    ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53488      80.239.137.145:https   ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53489      150.171.22.254:https   ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53491      a23-35-104-91:https    ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53492      13.107.237.254:https   ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53493      52.123.128.254:https   ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53494      13.107.42.254:https    ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53495      204.79.197.254:https   ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53496      13.107.18.254:https    ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53497      152.199.19.161:https   ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53498      13.107.246.254:https   ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53499      13.107.42.14:https     ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53500      104.215.5.225:https    ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53501      13.107.253.254:https   ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53502      20.141.10.208:https    ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53503      152.199.19.161:https   ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53504      20.190.181.5:https     ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53505      13.107.42.18:https     ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53506      a23-53-53-206:https    ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53507      13.107.42.18:https     ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53508      13.107.42.18:https     ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:53572      lr-in-f188:5228        ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:54929      40:https               ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:64183      124:4070               ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.2:64208      47:https               ESTABLISHED
TCP    [::1]:2619             DESKTOP-DRISJ7T:62737  ESTABLISHED
TCP    [::1]:62737            DESKTOP-DRISJ7T:2619   ESTABLISHED
```

Моя версия redis

```
Redis server v=3.0.504 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-3.6.0 bits=64 build=a4f7a6e86f2d60b3
```

Comment: Запускайте netstat с параметром **-a** и смотрите на статус LISTEN. В запущенных процессах redis-server присутствует

Comment: В таком случае и правда, localhost:6379 прослушивается. НО исключение никуда не делось. @Nikolay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось достаточно странным:

Что я сделал :

1. Удалил Redis с диска, и установил его по вот этому гайду
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_nFwPTHOMIY&ab_channel=Redis
2. Запустил сервер с помощью этой команды

   sudo service redis-server start
3. Изменил строку подключения на :

   localhost:6379,abortConnect=false

   Важное примечание, изменение строки, и попытка подключится к Redis который был установлен на диск, в моем случае не увенчался успехом. Только после установки по гайду, все заработало. Хотя на первый взгляд разницы никакой нет.

Также перед установкой по гайду попробовал установить Redis с сайта, версии 7.2.1 это тоже не помогло